# MongoDB db hosted on Windows 10 was stolen. Can I find out the IP address of computer that connected?

Tags: networking

[image]
This is the message I faced after I woke my computer up from sleep

Can I find out the IP address of the computer that connected and stole the DB? Does Windows 10 maintain logs of recent connections?

**Update**: I checked the router logs and this ip address is repeated several times in the logs: *82.211.191.129*. I substituted my ip address with `$MY_IP_ADDRESS`.

```
  5days, 10:22:28, DHCPC: Recv OFFER from server 82.211.191.129 with ip $MY_IP_ADDRESS.
  5days, 10:22:28, DHCPC: Send REQUEST to server 82.211.191.129 with request ip $MY_IP_ADDRESS.
  1days, 07:37:18, DHCPC: eth1 set ip $MY_IP_ADDRESS mask 255.255.255.192 gateway 82.211.191.129.
```

Can somebody please briefly explain what those logs mean? I have no idea what I'm looking at.

**Update #2**: Inside `mongod.log` file I found this 193.118.53.138 ip address was connected to the DB. I googled and this ip appears to be [blacklisted](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/193.118.53.138)

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.446+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60277","uuid":"14888a3e-9ed6-4ac8-81a9-c6a72302691e","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":14}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.518+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60277","uuid":"14888a3e-9ed6-4ac8-81a9-c6a72302691e","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":13}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.591+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60606","uuid":"c1a8d3d3-a248-4d00-9910-76eeef200fdc","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":14}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.663+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn16","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60606","uuid":"c1a8d3d3-a248-4d00-9910-76eeef200fdc","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":13}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.736+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60880","uuid":"8da8d4dd-a66e-4d4c-8937-4c8c429b6d4b","connectionId":17,"connectionCount":14}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:57.970+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn17","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:60880","uuid":"8da8d4dd-a66e-4d4c-8937-4c8c429b6d4b","connectionId":17,"connectionCount":13}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:58.042+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:33364","uuid":"37e844b4-1437-4f71-80ea-26426301af32","connectionId":18,"connectionCount":14}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:53:58.112+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"193.118.53.138:33364","uuid":"37e844b4-1437-4f71-80ea-26426301af32","connectionId":18,"connectionCount":13}}
```

167.248.133.63 was connected too. It also has been [reported](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/167.248.133.63).

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:05:54.033+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"167.248.133.63:33704","uuid":"2a078c1d-c476-45ad-bfdb-4e4d8b4f353a","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":14}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-03T14:05:54.356+04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"167.248.133.63:33704","uuid":"2a078c1d-c476-45ad-bfdb-4e4d8b4f353a","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":13}}
```

Comment: Look at the router logs.   Also, learn from this. Use a STRONG workstation password. Someone would have to knock at my computer for over 200,000 years to break in with an ordinary computer.

Comment: Surely MongoDB will have some log files…? Also why is it even reachable from the internet?

Comment: I'm totally new to it. I was experimenting scraping data from websites and storing it in the DB. The data wasn't important, so it's not a big deal to me. I open the port yesterday and today the db was stolen.

Comment: Windows Firewall has the capability to log inbound connections (to pfirewall.log), but AFAIK that is not enabled by default, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores that in your `mongod.log` in json format. Check it for `NETWORK` events, which includes network activities such as accepting connections.

Your router's `DHCPC` logs are probably worthless here, ignore them

Be aware that someone with unrestricted access into MongoDB can do anything the service can, including damaging or stealing data from other files on your machine. Don't open it up to the internet.